# Need to Filter a Table Based on Top N from Another Table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to return values for only the top 4 countries

```
Top 4 Fully Vaccinated 3 = 
VAR _Countries = TOPN(4,VALUES(DimCountries[Country]),[Fully Vaccinated %],DESC)

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    [Fully Vaccinated %],
   FILTER (
        ALL(DimCountries),DimCountries[Country] IN _Countries
    )
)
```

However, I still get all rows with a value
[image]

```
Fully Vaccinated % = 
DIVIDE(
    SUMX(
        GROUPBY(FactCovid19,DimCountries[CountryKey],"Current Fully Vacc",MAXX(CURRENTGROUP(),FactCovid19[FullyVaccinated])),
        [Current Fully Vacc]
    ),
[MTotalPopulation]
)
```

If I try to hardcode the country names it works fine. I also, tried the TOPN expression as a new table and it does return the 4 countries.

Does anyone knows what am I missing?

Comment: What you get from var TOPN(4,VALUES(DimCountries[Country]),[Fully Vaccinated %],DESC); Does this return only 4 countries?

Comment: It's a pitty you don't know how to provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ...

Comment: @msta42a correct.  It does

Comment: @Peter what do you mean? Do you need additional information?